# Azure Memory Resource Exhausted

Tags: azure, memory, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently hosting several dozen websites in Azure and recently started seeing a "Memory Resource Exhausted" warning within the portal blade for each web app:

[image: Memory Resource Exhausted]

I'm hosting my sites across two S3 Standard (Large) app service plans, I'm getting the warning on all sites regardless of which app service plan they are on.

Interestingly enough when looking at memory usage for either app service plan I am always below 40%, memory usage is actually rather consistent. I never see spikes or anything remotely close to 85% memory usage I'm being warned about.

[image: CPU and Memory Percentage]

My question is, am I misinterpreting the warning message? Is there a different memory resource that I need to be monitoring?

Comment: Have you made any progress? I started seeing the same thing and have no idea why

Comment: Ditto, add me to the list. I've been obsessive about Dispose()ing objects that need it (mainly through the 'using' keyword), yet I've hit this issue with Azure at least twice. It *must* be bad design decisions on my part, but finding them is another matter.

Comment: I'm actually thinking it was a bug in Azure, by making no changes and seeing no changes in the CPU and memory consumption of my app service plan the warnings simply disappeared. I have not seen any warnings in any apps in several weeks and at no point while I was seeing the warnings did I notice any performance issues or degradation in app services that I might have expected to see.

Comment: I'm getting these now, even though the app hasn't been modified and this is our quiet period. Worrying...

Comment: a ploy to get me to panic and upgrade the server is my guess :)

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, even though memory never going above 60% utilization, even when measuring each instance in my autoscale.

Comment: There's an AVG, MIN, and MAX measure.  I've seen AVG hover at 60, while min and max lines are consistently at min: 40 and max: 80 or 90.  You might just be looking at the default which is AVG.

Answer (score 1):

Check working set and private set memory from kudu. There could be a problem in the private set.

Comment: Great information, I'm seeing the data but don't yet know how to interpret it. If this is indeed the issue I'll update this question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Can you view working set and private set for App Service Plan or just each App??

Comment: Made a [SO question of above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291287/azure-app-service-memory-usage-where-to-see-full-breakdown)