# Running out of memory in Azure with 50% utilization

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I ran into a situation where out of memory exceptions were generated in our Azure App Service for a .Net Core Web API even though memory & utilization topped 50% in the App Service Plan (P2V2: 7GB RAM).

I have looked at this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291287/azure-app-service-memory-usage-where-to-see-full-breakdown) to check private bytes and other things but still don't see where the memory of exhaustion comes from. I see a max usage of 1.5GB on the memory working set which is well below the 7GB.

Nothing shows up under Support + Troubleshooting -> Resource Health or App Service Advisor.

I am not sure where to look next and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Azure App Services caps memory usage at 1.5G by default. But you can change this behaviour with this application setting (to be added under Configuration):

`WEBSITE_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB = 3072`

See also my answer here:
[Is there way to determine why Azure App Service restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021644/is-there-way-to-determine-why-azure-app-service-restarted/68191750#68191750)

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I've tried searching for it but couldn't find anything that explicitly called out a default memory cap on an app service.

Comment: @AndrewMoreno I received this info from MS during the resolving of the issue I reported.

Comment: This is only partialy true. `WEBSITE_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB` affects only Windows Containers deployed apps. OP does not mention anything about containers. Unless your app is container deployed, this setting will have no effect. Source: [list of config values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#custom-containers)

Answer (score 0):

The Metrics view on the portal can only go up to a 1 minute granularity level. 
(The default is 5 minutes)

This means that each metric point is an average value over a 60-second interval. 
It may be spiking up and down over 60 seconds, so you need a more real-time view.

Try the SCM console (Advanced Tools > Go), and check the Process Explorer to see the actual memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks Jasonh for answering. This is the same view as Process Explorer under Monitoring. It gives me the current memory utilized. I can certainly go there to get a granular info on a per process but it does not explain how I can get a memory exhaustion when the process reached 1.5GB which is well below the allocated 7GB.